# Odds of observing numbers in a specific range, given a weighted random number generator

Tags: statistics

Say I have a weighted random number generator, which generates discrete numbers in a range with a known probability - for example, it generates 1 25% of the time, and 0 the rest.

How do I calculate the odds that I will see k 1's, where k is in the range [a,b], after observing n randomly generated numbers?

Comment: Depends a lot on your distribution. You hint that it is fully discrete. What are the possible outcomes?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean - it's discrete in the sense of it generates only the values 0,1; the expected outcome is the ability to generate a sentence along the lines of: "The odds of seeing anywhere between 200 and 300 1s after observing 1000 randomly generated number are 60%"

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the event of your random number being in the given range a "success".  If the random numbers are independent and the probability of success is $p$, then the number $X$ of successes in $n$ trials has a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$.  In particular, $\mathbb P(X=k) = {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do calculations by hand (i.e., using look up tables) instead of adding up a bunch of binomial distribution terms, then calculate the mean and variance of your binomial and then approximate as a Gaussian with the same mean and variance.